# How to create a simple dropdown list with php linking to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

Hi there Im very new to PHP and Im having issues trying to make drop-down list with php connecting to my mysql db. I am able to connect to the database no problem as no error message is showing up when I load up the php document online.

However from my research I just cant seem to find what Im looking for. I have made a table in mysql with the necessary ids and values. Below is my code within select tags if even thats a good way to do it? if anyone can help much appreciated.

```
<select>
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect ("host", "username", "password");

if (!$db)
{
  echo "Sorry! Can't connect to database";
     exit();
         }
        //table name on mysql db = users3
        ?>
          </select>
```

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and solve common problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run PHP inside of an HTML select tag. PHP runs server side (in the background).

You'll need to create your dropdown menu using Javascript and HTML, then have have your javascript code call your PHP via AJAX. There are a number of ways doing this, but the basic idea is to have an event bound to each item in your dropdown list. When you click one of your list items, your javascript uses AJAX to call your PHP which queries the database.

That's a pretty high level description of it but hopefully it gives you a sense of where you need to go from here.

Regards,

--Drew

Comment: You do not need AJAX. The OP never mentioned AJAX, you are implying that AJAX is a necessity.

Comment: @sudo Yeah I misunderstood the question. If the OP is just printing out some data in a select element there's no need for AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is obviously missing any SQL select query.

The following code was adapted from W3Schools, I suggest you have a read over some examples using mysqli here [Mysql select query example](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Included is a select list that is also courtesy of W3Schools, [HTML form elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp)

I implore you to read some examples at W3Schools.

**HTML**

```
<select name="items"><?php echo getSelectItems(); ?></select>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
function getSelectItems() {
    $servername = "host";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "itemDB";

    $output = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT itemName FROM items";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $output .= '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $row["itemName"] . '</option>';
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to third-rate sites like w3schools. Those examples are often full of really outdated code, chock full of SQL injection bugs, and worse. The PHP documentation is often significantly better and is up-to-date.